# How To Create A Log For Failed Events

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, scripting

I have a very simple PowerShell script where I am copying data that's in one folder, and is putting it on an external hard drive. I would like to create a log file for failed events (meaning if some of the data was not copied) The data can be a .txt file. Here is the simple log file I have.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Copy-Item -Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Cummins Allisson\TempData\iFX1\* -Destination D:\backup -recurse

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Remove-Item C:\Program Files (x86)\Cummins Allison\TempData\iFX1\* -recurse
```

I appreciate the help on this. I am very new to PowerShell and by no means an expert.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [common parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) `-ErrorAction` and `-ErrorVariable` to assist you in this.

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\Program Files (x86)\Cummins Allisson\TempData\iFX1\* -Destination D:\backup -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable events

Remove-Item C:\Program Files (x86)\Cummins Allison\TempData\iFX1\* -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable events
```

Then you will have the variable `$events` which will contain all the details of the errors that occurred for both of those commands. `SilentlyContinue` surpresses the error output from the screen which, in addition to being stored in the default variable `$error` is stored in `$events`.

```
$events.Exception | Set-Content c:\temp\log.log
```

This would give you sample data like

```
An item with the specified name C:\temp\data2\data already exists.
An item with the specified name C:\temp\data2\data\folder1 already exists.
An item with the specified name C:\temp\data2\data\folder1\folder2 already
```

exists.

Which only happened since I didn't use the `-Force` parameter for `Copy-Item` which would have overwritten the files.

**Side Note**

I should think you would be able to use [`Move-Item`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849852.aspx) for this code as well.

Depeding on how ofter this code is run in the same session you might need to set the variable `$events` to `$null` or equivalent so you don't get duplicate output.